# React-native - Axios GET request throws network error in Android emulator

Tags: android, api, react-native, android-emulator, axios

I am new to React-native. I am trying to perform a simple get request using the following code:

```
axios.get('http://push-cycling-backend.dev/api/test')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I have tested the request using Postman and everything works fine, but when I run the request in my react-native app using the ANDROID EMULATOR, I get the following error:

> Error: Network Error

I have a feeling this is because I am trying to access a Api end point hosted locally through Xammp via the Android emulator, but I have no idea what to do.
Please any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: can you see the network request in debugger?

Comment: Hello. The request does not appear in the network tab of the remote js debugger. I think it should also be noted that in order to get the remote JS debugger to work, I have been changing the url form the default http://10.0.0.2:8081/debugger-ui/  to http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ as the default url does not appear to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working by changing the request URL from http://push-cycling-backend.dev/api/test to http://10.0.2.2:80/push-cycling-backend/public/api/test. From what i understand, since the android emulator, emulates a actual device, I believe 'localhost' was referring to an address on the emulated device instead of my local server 10.0.2.2 is something like a keyword that refers to your local machines ip address.